# Could not execute google form api on google developer documentation

Tags: google-api

I got the below popup when I tried to execute the google form api from google developer documentation.

I tried this same process with google docs api which work perfectly. I tried tp turn on less secure app access, but it seems google made it unavailable.

what is the other way out.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: could you give us some more information as to exactly what documentation you are following and what link you clicked on.

Comment: this the documentation am following i clicked 
 on the execute button at the right sidebar of the page  https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/get

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with the try me on forms.

I have logged it on the issue form and im going to see if i can find someone at google to ping about it

- [Forms.get try me not working](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238911019)

I suspect however that this may have something to do with the app being in early access. That being said i would have expected a different error message if that was the issue.

It is most likely due to the permission for the client they are using.  It is an internal error and not something you have done.

May i suggest creating your own app and testing it that way. Just remember this api is in early access so be sure that you fill out the form found on this page [Google Forms API now available in open beta](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/12/google-forms-api-now-available-in-open.html)

> Developers can apply to join our Early Adopter Program and begin developing using the Google Forms API by filling out this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdSol7REBlfqk3J9i8TD__B6f7185ynkVw7HkJQ3Rg62W36sw/viewform).

Comment: yea...i'm using the REST/HTTP option of the service account and everytime i tried to access the apis with the generated access token. i keep getting this error 
 "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }

Comment: And have used this same process to access Google docs api though with different scope

Comment: Are you using a service account by any chance?  Or did you forget to apply for access?

Comment: and the form is not expected to be filled again since google have made it generally available

Comment: and am using a service account

Comment: the docs still say its needed.  Did you configured domain wide deligation with the service account

Comment: yes.... i did that...i added the client id of the service account and added the scope needed for the apis

Comment: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdSol7REBlfqk3J9i8TD__B6f7185ynkVw7HkJQ3Rg62W36sw/closedform this is the link for early adopted form, the form is closed

Comment: it has worked...i had to give the service account email access to the form on my google drive.....thanks